# Convert Array of Objects into Object containing key and value as Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ember.js

I am getting a response as Array of Objects

```
myObject is Array [Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

I want to convert it into an Object with some key and value as above Array of Objects

```
myObject should convert to Object {someKey : Array[4]}
```

I am trying to do it like:

```
var someKeys = myObject.map(a => a.arr_key); 

myObject[someKeys[0]] = myObject;
```

but failing, need some help here. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you do something like this? `const object = { someKey: yourArray }`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, sorry. I misunderstood your question. You should edit your question and provide those extra details.

Comment: @DerekHopper i want to modify the existing Array of Objects structure

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myObject = [{},{},{},{}];
myObject = { 'key': myObject };

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you rephrase?

Comment: The way I am implementing, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Yes? Your code and my code are very different. I don't know how broken your code is because there isn't enough of it to determine that. This line `myObject[someKeys[0]] = myObject;` doesn't make sense. You're asking to turn an array into an object that has a key with the array as the value. What you're doing doesn't do that at all. It's trying to find whatever index `someKeys[0]` is inside of the myObject array and push the entire array inside that index.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
    var someKeys = myObject.map(a => a.arr_key); 

    let newObj = {};

    newObj[someKeys[0]] = myObject;

    myObject = newObj;
```

Previosuly I was trying to access Array of Objects as a Object directly, which isn't legit.